# emacs ocaml REPL: "Searching for program: no such file or directory, ocaml"

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, ocaml, opam

I'm trying to set up OCaml in Ubuntu 16.04.3 on VirtualBox. I'm new to all of them; please pardon my ignorance. I installed `opam` using

```
wget https://raw.github.com/ocaml/opam/master/shell/opam_installer.sh -O - | sh -s /usr/local/bin
```

and added

```
. /home/<username>/.opam/opam-init/init.sh > /dev/null 2> /dev/null || true
```

to my `~/.profile` file according to the instructions following the `opam` installation. I installed `tuareg` using `opam install tuareg` and `GNU emacs 24.5.1` using `sudo apt-get install emacs`.

When I tried to use the `ocaml` REPL by typing `M-x run-ocaml` and `return` in emacs, I got `OCaml REPL to run: ocaml`; when I hit `enter` again, I got

```
Searching for program: no such file or directory, ocaml
```

I then tried `M-x shell` to see if I can run `ocaml` from shell, and I noticed that I need to use `opam switch` every time I want to run `ocaml` from the terminal/shell; if I directly type `ocaml`, I would get

```
The program 'ocaml' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install ocaml-interp
```

I'm not sure whether this has anything to do with the problem I'm getting.

As a second try, I went back to emacs and typed `M-x run-ocaml`, hit `return`, and hit `return` again at `OCaml REPL to run:` (this time without the `ocaml`). This opened up a new buffer:

[image: output file descriptor closed]

But when I tried to type things in the new buffer, say `1+1;;`, and hit `shift-return`, I get `Output file descriptor of OCaml is closed`, as shown above.

I've been reading different documentations and threads for instructions, but none of them quite describe my situation. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try something like `M-x run-ocaml`, `return`, and then type something like `/usr/bin/opam config exec -- ocaml` (or whatever the path to your opam installation) instead of `ocaml`

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the problem by following [realworldocaml](https://github.com/realworldocaml/book/wiki/installation-instructions). I realized that I had several problems in my post, so I'm using this answer to
share the solution to each as suggested in the link.

@ghilesZ's answer perfectly solves the problem in my question title (thank you!). I should have added the path of `ocaml` either in the `M-x` command (as the above answer suggests) or in the `~/.emacs` configuration file (as the link suggests). The path can be obtained by typing `which ocaml` in the terminal after completing the step below.

The need to type

```
eval `opam config env`
```

to run `ocaml` from the terminal can be solved by adding the line to the `~/.bashrc` file. This is because typing the command in the current shell only sets things up for the current shell. In order for future shells to automatically set things up, it needs to be added in the login scripts.